# custom encode a string

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I convert every character in a string to a number for encoding.

My encoding key will be.

```
a = 01
b = 02
c = 03
d = 04
.
.
z = 26
```

So suppose I enter "dog" in my cell, it should be converted to "04 15 07".

Will be working in Google Spreadsheet, so a JavaScript function would be helpful.

Comment: You could create a lookup table which maps characters to numbers as in your OP.  Or you could use VBA to avoid a headache.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your Comment i created the following Javascript Code:

```
var letters =  ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];

function giveNumbercode(someString){
    var numbercode="";
    for(var i = 0; i < someString.length; i++){
        var letter = someString[i];
        var number = letters.indexOf(letter) + 1;
        if(number < 10){
            number = "0"+number
        }
        numbercode += " "+number
    }
    alert("Your Numbercode: "+numbercode+"");
    return numbercode;
}
```

All u have to do is call the function and it will give u the numbercode for Example :

giveNumbercode("dog") will return "Your Numbercode:  04 15 07"

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells you wish to process and run this short macro:

```
Sub EnCoder()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        v = r.Text
        For i = 97 To 122
            v = Replace(v, Chr(i), Format(i - 96, " 00"))
        Next i
        r.Value = v
    Next r
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

Comment: Thanks did work in excel. However, due to the changes in the requirements I am asked to use Google Spreadsheet. 
Can anyone convert the VBA code to javascript?

Comment: @VarDOS  Edit your original question to include the proper tags and you may get a better answer.